# Utilise Flexslider caption outslide of Flexslider

Tags: javascript, css, flexslider

Due to a layout issue I am trying to utilise the .flex-caption outside of the flexslider itself.

Can you think of a way I can achieve this?

Ideally the markup would be structured like this:

```
<div class="flexslider gallery">
<ul class="slides">
<li><img src="image.jpg"  /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<p class="flex-caption">Caption</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

This solved it without the need for an additional slider:

```
$captions = $('.captions');

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    controlNav: true,
    directionNav: false,
    slideshow: false,
    prevText: "Previous",
    nextText: "Next",
    useCSS: true,
    touch: true,
    start: function() {
        $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption');
        $captions.html($activecaption.text());        
    },
    after: function() {
        $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption');
        $captions.html($activecaption.text());
    }
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hq7Q/1/).
​

Comment: Does anyone know how to apply formatting and styles to the captions element? Specifically I would like to add additional divs so that I can have a line break. But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue and found a link that helped me solve the issue. Also this is assuming you are looking for the caption to change with the slider navigation.

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/108

Basically it involves creating two separate flexsliders and linking them together with navigation controls using this option on the caption slider:

```
start: function(slider){

            $('.flex-direction-nav li a').click(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              var dir = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
              slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget(dir));
            });
        }
```

FYI though, the functionality doesn't seem to work on mobile. Looking into that further.

Comment: This solves it without the need for an additional slider: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hq7Q/1/

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked well for me. Thanks!
You can also do this with an image caption, instead of text.

```
after: function() {
   $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption img');
   $activecaption.clone().prependTo($captions);
}
```

you want to copy the element, first, then prepend it.